# MVC 3 Pass link value into controller and populate textbox

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I've been searching this web-site and other sources for an answer, but haven't found anything useful. I need the simplest solution, as I am only just starting to learn MVC and AJAX.
I have a grid that retreives it's records from a database, each row contains the generated links in separate columns: "Edit" and "Delete". The actual record names also come up as links, which contain the id of it's corresponding record: .../ItemType/ItemDetails/1 . Now I want to take this id and pass it into Controller when it's being clicked. The links are not wrapped with names, so I couldn't think of how I would call a click function on it?

```
$("#<link I want>").click()
```

and then pass the whole href and get the last character of the string? Or may be there are other ways?

I then want to use this id, to find the record and populate the textbox and drop-down with it's values

```
$("#txtItemName").val(<value from controller>)
$("#txtItemPrice").val(<value from controller>)
$("#ItemTypes").selected value = <value from controller>
```

I just have absolutely no idea in how to pass the information to controller and back in one go, so that I can update the partial view.

I'm interested in any sort of helpful information be it ideas of how to achieve it some other way, or examples, or solutions.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something simple like HTML5 `data` attributes. For example, say this is your link

```
<a href="ItemType/ItemDetails/1" data-item-id="1">Item Name</a>
```

Using jQuery's [`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method, you can get the ID

```
$('#<link I want>').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).data('item-id');
    // and so on
});
```